# Set score in local sotrage only if a higher number

Tags: html, jquery, local-storage

Hi im trying to find a way to use local storage to save a high score, i have a simple script that sets the score each time the user plays.

```
      localStorage.score = $(".score").text();
      $(".highscore").text(localStorage.score);
```

However I now want to expand on it and it only to update the score if its a new high score and also sets the date it was achieved. Thank you

Comment: then first read the localStorage, compare it and update it only if it's higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know where you want to have your storage, in a separate storage item, or change it to an object and add values that will hold both the score and date.

Then when using localStorage, to insert a JS **object** correctly it has to be converted into JSON: `JSON.stringify()`, then when retreiving just parse it: `JSON.parse()`

Here's a working example:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="score">35</div>
<div class="highscore"></div>
<div class="highscore-date"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    let date = new Date();
    localStorage.score =
        localStorage.score ?
            Number($(".score").text()) > JSON.parse(localStorage.score).score ?
                JSON.stringify({
                    "score": $(".score").text(),
                    "date": `${date.toDateString()} at ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`
                })
            : localStorage.score
        : JSON.stringify({
            "score": $(".score").text(),
            "date": `${date.toDateString()} at ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`
        })
    $(".highscore").text(JSON.parse(localStorage.score).score);
    $(".highscore-date").text(JSON.parse(localStorage.score).date);
});
```

This script checks whether the score item has been set in the localStorage first. If it exists, then first cast the score value into a `Number` since it's being read as a string, then check wheter it's greater than the current value, and update accordingly

And here an object is used to hold both values for score and date in the same storage item

---

Edit:

```
JSON.stringify({
   "score": JSON.parse(localStorage.score).score,
   "date": JSON.parse(localStorage.score).date
})
```

refractored to `localStorage.score`

Comment: Why are you making this less readable by using ternary operators instead of just `if else`?

Comment: @gre_gor Ternary operators are actually easier and they only become unreadable when you have more than 2 nested amongst each other. The indentation I've used here clearly makes it readable

Comment: You have more than 2 nested among each other. If you need to make them across multiple lines, then you should have used `if else`. You are just misusing the ternary operator.

Comment: And writing `JSON.parse(localStorage.score)` 5 times is also bad code. And also parsing `localStorage.score` twice just to write it back unchanged.